# Вывести ключ и значение массива each

Tags: javascript

```
var json = [ 
    "1-1-1-1-1":{
        "a":{
            "Hi-Gear": ["HG2222", "HG2205"],
            "FENOM": ["FN338N"]
        }
    },
];


$.each(json,function(index,value){
  console.log('Ключ: ' + index + '; Значение: ' + value);
});
```

Как в console.log правильно вывести ключ FENOM и его значение FN338N ?

Comment: Такого массива быть не может.

Comment: И нужен чуть более широкий пример json... в частности: ключи `a` и `FENOM` везде одинаковые, а отличаются только ключи "1-1-1-1-1" ?

Comment: Отличаются только ключи "1-1-1-1-1" , a и FENOM всегда одинаковы

Answer (score 2):

Цикл `for( let key in object )` — в нем переменная `key` собственно ключ, а значение этого ключа можно получать через `object[key]`

```js
var json = {
  "1-1-1-1-1": {
    "a": {
      "Hi-Gear": ["HG2222", "HG2205"],
      "FENOM": ["FN338N"]
    }
  },
  "2-2-2-2-2": {
    "a": {
      "Hi-Gear": ["HG2222", "HG2205"],
      "FENOM": ["F12345", "F54321"]
    }
  },
};

for( var key in json ){
  console.log(
    'Ключ: ' + key + '; Путь: json["' + key + '"].a.FENOM; Значение: ' + json[key].a.FENOM
  );
}
```

Здесь выводимые массивы автоматически превращаются в строки из-за соединения со строками. Но по отдельности `json[key].a.FENOM` можно использовать как обычный массив. Или дописать `JSON.stringify( json[key].a.FENOM )` если нужно его выводить именно со скобками.